# Sending an object throug a webservice and retrieve data in asp.net or silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, silverlight

I am using silverlight to develop a windows gadget,I need to call a asp.net web service and which is return an object with some data.
I want to receive that object and show data.

My codes are below

Web services code.

```
[WebMethod]
        public userdata LogIn(string username,string user_password)
        {

                return udata;
            }
            return new userdata();
        }
    }
```

My custom class code is

```
 public class userdata
    {
        string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        string userName;

        public string UserName
        {
            get { return userName; }
            set { userName = value; }
        }
        string department;

        public string Department
        {
            get { return department; }
            set { department = value; }
        }
        string designation;

        public string Designation
        {
            get { return designation; }
            set { designation = value; }
        }
        string email;

        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }
        string mobile;

        public string Mobile
        {
            get { return mobile; }
            set { mobile = value; }
        }
        string ip;

        public string Ip
        {
            get { return ip; }
            set { ip = value; }
        }
        string id;

        public string Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }


    }
```

it returns

```
<userdata>
<Name>Asik</Name>
<UserName>asikcse</UserName
><Department>technical</Department>
<Designation>Software Programmer</Designation>
<Id>1</Id>
</userdata>
```

And in the end of my project I add web references as that references but havent any solution to this.

```
LoginServiceSoapClient login = new LoginServiceSoapClient();
            login.LogInCompleted+=new EventHandler<LogInCompletedEventArgs>(login_LogInCompleted);
            login.LogInAsync(log._nameText, log._surnameText);
        }

        void login_LogInCompleted(object sender, LogInCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

              How can I retrieve this object returned by webmethod

        }
```

Comment: You need to simplify your question... Remove any code that has nothing to do with your question. If your problem is XML related, then remove all your database code from your web service.  The code in your question should simply return a static instance of your userdata class.  Also, what does "that I don't know" mean?  Do you know the error message in the XML, but don't understand it?  If so, you should share all the details of the XML exception.

Comment: I have been edited,and in the webmethod it return xml data,in my end how can i use this object or xml data

Answer (score 0):

So you will need to create a class in the silverlight application to hold the data, I suggest just copying the userdata class.  Then you will need to make an request to that endpoint to get the data.  This can be done using the WebClient class.  Then use the DataContractSerializer to turn the xml into an object.  Here is an example:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

var data = webClient.DownloadString("<your endpoint>");  //You can do this async too

var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(UserData));

Byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);

UserData userData;

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    userData = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as UserData;
}
```

There are some smarter ways to do this.